# Python - How to split if a value contains more than 2 characters and add '-' between it

Tags: python, split, slice

So I am trying to do something simple yet hard to think out now.

So basically I have random number generator where it sometimes is:

```
12
1234
23
2345
```

etc etc..

and basically what I want to do is that whenever there is more than 2 characters. Add a space and add a '-' between it meaning a output off:

```
12
12 3-4
23
23 4-5
```

I tried to do a split but it just remove the last two characters

I would appreciate all kind of help!

Soulution:

```
numbers = ['12', '1234', '23', '2345']

for number in numbers:
    number = str(number) # convert each to string just in case
    if len(number) > 2:
       number = number[:2] + ' ' + number[2] + '-' + number[3:]
    print(number)
```

Comment: Why the downvotes without commenting the issue :( ?

Comment: What if the random number is 3 or 5 digits? What is the output? You're better off reading this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq

Comment: You forgot to add what you tried and how it failed, also include your attempted code in the question

Comment: I have created so it will always contain maximum of 4 characters only :)

Comment: Alright! I did not know. I will do it now

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh when I just wanted to add someone gave n answer which I think would solve my issue! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = ['12', '1234', '23', '2345']

for number in numbers:
    number = str(number) # convert each to string just in case
    if len(number) > 2:
       number = number[:2] + ' ' + number[2] + '-' + number[3:]
    print(number)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue and I appreciate it alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating new_list

```
numbers=list(map(str,numbers)) # to convert int to str
new_list=[i[:2] + ' ' + i[2] + '-' + i[3:] if len(i)>2 else i for i in numbers]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to change to `str` then use formatted print with list comprehension

```
lst = [12, 1234, 23, 2345]
lst = map(str, lst)
res = [f'{i[:2]} {i[2]}-{i[3]}' if len(i) > 2 else i for i in lst]
# ['12', '12 3-4', '23', '23 4-5']
```